# HTML parsing unknown selector needed

Tags: html, css, parsing, jsoup, selector

Using Jsoup an html parsing java library, i have located this from a website:

```
<div class="jobCardListingTitle">
                <a href="/jobs/hospitality-tourism/other/listing-846200105.htm" id="ListView_CardRepeater_ctl02_card_JobCard_JobCardTitleLink">Cafe staff wanted!</a>
```

using: `Elements Jobs = doc.select("div.jobCardListingTitle a");`

however i want to retrieve "cafe staff wanted" but i only know how to retrieve href `System.out.println(Job.attr("href"));` and id... `System.out.println(Job.attr("id"));`

How do i find this string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `<ElementsObject>.html()`.

In your case:

```
System.out.println(Job.html());
```

There also is the `<ElementsObject>.text()` property, that may worth a look.

Comment: Always a pleasure sir. Welcome to SO.